# How to set up Browsersync to correctly serve AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-sync

I'm trying to set up Browsersync for loading documents via AJAX.

All files are stored in the project root folder:

```
gulpfile.js
index.html
load-me.html
```

Simplified Browsersync settings

```
gulp.task('server', () => 

  browserSync.init({
    files: '*.html',
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    },
    port: 9000,
    notify: false
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Try to load content via AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>

  <button>Click me</button>
  <div id="result"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
      $('#result').load('load-me.html');
    });
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

load-me.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Yay!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>10x, God. It's loaded!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I start MAMP server everything works fine. But Browsersync settings are corrupted. And I can't fix it. Please, help, who knows.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because browser-sync modifies the response each time you request for an `html` page. The modified `html` page comes with a script that has a `document.write`. If you check your `html` source code you should see something like this:

```
<script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.12.3.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>
```

This happens to occur for `load-me.html` page when requesting it in a `browser-sync` server as well. The modified html response that's inserted in the `#result` element will also have the script above inserted which runs the `document.write` all over again and thereby overriding the entire html page.

There are two options for the solution:

1. Target specific html tags that you want to be inserted inside `#result` from the `load-me.html` html page by **[loading page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)**. Example below.

**Javascript**

```
$('#result').load('load-me.html h1');
```

The example above should only insert the `h1` element inside the `load-me.html` page, and not the entire `load-me.html` html content.

2. You can choose to only have the html contents that you need inside `load-me.html` without the `html`, and `body` tags.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try solution as soon as possible :)

Comment: 10x, @ryeballar. It's loaded! )